# Reuse Primary Key in another Django model field

Tags: python, django

Is it possible to reference the primary key in another field in a Django model?

For example, let's say I want to have a field looking like `BUG0001` corresponding to the entry with `pk=1`. What is the best way to achieve this?

I think it is best to keep the primary key as an integer as it is easier to deal with, and I guess formatting the primary key every time is not very effective.

Comment: did either my answer or Vishal's answer worked for you?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I'm still looking for a solution (currently I'm just formatting the string after querying the result...)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it possible and easy to do. Just do this

First make primary key
`from django.db import models class Fruit(models.Model): name = models.CharField(max_length=100,primary_key=True)`

And then call it where you want as foreign key
`foreign= models.ForeignKey(Reporter, on_delete=models.CASCADE)`

Comment: I would rather keep an auto increment integer in the primary key field.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

```
class Product(models.Model):
     other= models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)

     def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.another = "BUG%d" %(self.pk)
        super(Product, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

You can check out [python string formatting](https://www.learnpython.org/en/String_Formatting).

Another way is to use `@property` [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/models/#model-methods)or `@cached_property`[doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/utils/#module-django.utils.functional) .

In your case, @cached_property may be better. `property` and `cached_property` will not be saved in database. but you can call it in your template as if this is another model field.

Obvious benefit of using property and cahced_property is that you will not need to save to db every time you need to save model.

```
from django.utils.functional import cached_property

class Product(models.Model):
     # since we want to have "another" as a property, you do not need to 
     # generate a field called "another"
     #another= models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
      
     somefield = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
     
     @cached_property
     def another(self):
        return "BUG%d" %(self.pk)
        # not sure why the above string formatting not working for you.
        # you can simply do:
        return "BUG" + str(self.pk)

     def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Product, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: When I save one Product entry the another field is replaced by None: `BUG/None`

Comment: oops! My bad. since ```pk``` is interger, i should use ```%d``` rather than ```%s```.Please see updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for the correction but the pk is still None. After some research it seems the pk cannot get referenced prior to the entry creation.

Comment: I have tested this in my project without problem it shows BUG1

Comment: My model is identical to what you have in your answer (no other model created)

Comment: well migration should not affect this. I am really not sure why it is not working for you. Please see my updated answer 1) I add another way to represent this. 2) also add ```property``` and ```cached_property``` which shoud be better for you do use.